# How to list require_once()'s searched paths in PHP?

Tags: php, include, require

We've all seen this error before:

```
Warning: require_once(test/blah.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/narf/narf.inc on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'test/blah.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/home/narf/inc:/home3/narf/php:/home3/narf/inc/dev:') in /home/narf/narf.inc on line 3
```

Super annoying.

**Here's what I'm looking for:
Some sort of PHP snippet that will list the paths that are being searched for the include file.**

From what I can see, I've set up my path correctly (the above include scenario is simply a fabrication), and I can include the file successfully from other portions of the project.

However, I just can't get it to work.  If I had a list of locations that were being searched, I could easily track down the path that I'm missing and identify why my require/include isn't working.

Thoughts?  Does someone have a snippet kicking around they could share?

Thanks a million in advance! :)

Edit: For what it's worth, I think I tracked down the problem, but if you've still got something that could help out, it would be great for future misconfigurations! :)

Edit 2: Thanks for all who have answered.  Getting the include path is nice, but I'm looking for actual **absolute** paths of directories that are being searched.  The reason why I'm being picky is because it gets confusing when using a require() or include() along with relative paths.  Also, I suspect that there are some other gotchas such as (potentially) whether or not symlinks are followed on a given setup, etc.

Comment: Ugh.  Finally found the right path.  It turns out I needed: " require_once('../../../www/blog/wp-load.php');"  This makes NO sense, but at least my script is running now.  Maybe I'll whip up a script for everyone later that lists all searched absolute paths.

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned originally that I'm using relative paths (sometimes with '../x/y/z', and other times just with 'x/y/z') in my include statement (as shown above), so PHP's include path is only partially relevant (only in the case of the 'x/y/z' inclusion).  From include()'s documentation: "If a path is defined — whether absolute ... or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the manual's page of [**`include`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) :

> Files are included based on the file
> path given or, if none is given, the
> `include_path` specified. 
> If the file
> isn't found in the `include_path`,
> `include()` will finally check in the
> calling script's own directory and the
> current working directory before
> failing

And the [**`include_path`**][2] is a configuration directive that *(quoting)* :

> Specifies a list of directories where
> the `require()`, `include()`, `fopen()`,
> `file()`, `readfile()` and
> `file_get_contents()` functions look for
> files.

It can be configured in your `php.ini` file, or at runtime, using the [**`set_include_path()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function.

And, of course, to get the include path, you have [**`get_include_path()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php).

Comment: Choosing this answer as the 'correct' answer because it will help the most amount of people that come to this page.  Technically, I was looking for something that would give me a list of absolute paths that were being searched, but it seems that this does not exist.  Creating a function to do so would not be too complicated; perhaps I'll revisit this question and post a code snippet later.  Thanks to everyone who answered! :)

Answer (score 6):

You want the function `get_include_path()` [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php)

Answer (score 1):

The path is listed in the error message: it's the values in the include_path